# How to make the model take the shape of a skeleton animation when both files are extracted from a game?

Tags: modeling, rendering, texturing

Okay I am very new at this. I am trying to export some models from a game, however the default pose of the model isn't what I want. Instead the pose that I want is from an animation, but I am not sure how to get the pose of the model to match that of the animation. I am not trying to get a animated image. I just need a single image from one frame of the animation. The animation skeleton is included in the blend file and was originally a .smd file.

Any help that can be provided is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and keep it to a single topic. You can ask many questions, but not on the same post

Comment: @cegaton Topic fixed and I created another topic for the texture problem.